# Generate random color

Tags: c#, random

I want to generate a random color but i get this error,and i don`t now why.
The method "FromRgb" recives only byte parametres. 
Conversion is done wrong?

This is the error:
"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(byte, byte, byte)' has some invalid arguments"

This is the code:

```
Random r = new Random();
int n = r.Next(255);
string f = n.ToString();
textbox1.Text = f;
byte q = Convert.ToByte(r);
Color color = Color.FromRgb(r.Next(),r.Next(),r.Next());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Byte[] b = new Byte[3];
rnd.NextBytes(b);
Color color = Color.FromRgb(b[0],b[1],b[2]);
```

For more information about the `NextBytes` method please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You've got the dots there already, when you converted the output from into to a byte:

```
byte q = Convert.ToByte(r);
```

Just apply that to the paramaters

```
Color color = Color.FromRgb(Convert.ToByte(r.Next()),
Convert.ToByte(r.Next()),Convert.ToByte(r.Next()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
Random r = new Random();
Color randomColor= new Color();
randomColor.A = 255; //alpha channel of the color
randomColor.R = (byte)r.Next(0, 255); //red channel
randomColor.G = (byte)r.Next(0, 255); //green channel
randomColor.B = (byte)r.Next(0, 255); //blue channel

SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(randomColor);
```

Comment: `Color` struct is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about why you try this:

```
byte q = Convert.ToByte(r);
```

If you think that this would lead to r returning bytes instead of integers: this is not the case. It tries to create a byte that represents the Random object. This is hardly possible so it simply throws an InvalidCastException.

Instead you would have to cast the integers that are being returned by r.Next(). The reason is that integers have a smaller range of values than bytes. To avoid resulting errors there is no implicit conversion from byte to int. Therefore you would have to make an explicit cast:

```
Random r = new Random();
Color color = Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(),(byte)r.Next(),(byte)r.Next());
```

This is possible, but I would encourage you to use @Christos solution, as it is more elegant.

For more information on implicit numeric conversions click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx).